# Mongoose .findOne is not a function - using passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I keep getting this error while attempting to use my local strategy by passport lib.

```
TypeError: UserModel.findOne is not a function
```

I have looked around for hours but can't seem to find a solution that works for my problem. Here is my user.model and auth.services files.

**user.model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const cryptor = require('../services/bcrypt.services');
const authServices = require('../services/auth.services');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({

    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        required: [true, 'Email is required'],
        validate: {
            validator: function(email) {
                return validator.isEmail(email);
            },
            message: function (props) { `${props.value} is not an valid email` }
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        minlength: [6, 'Password too short'],
        lowercase: true,
        required: true
    },

    conversations: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref: 'Conversation' }]
});

UserSchema.methods = {

    async _hashPassword(password) {
        this.password = await cryptor.hashAsync(password);
    },

    async authUser(password) {
        return await cryptor.compareAsync(password, this.password);
    },

    createToken() {
        return jwt.sign({
            _id: this._id
        }, authServices.privateKey);
    },

    toAuthJWT() {
        return {
            _id: this._id,
            email: this.email,
            token: this.createToken()
        };
    },

    toJSON() {
        return {
            _id: this._id,
            email: this.email
        }
    }

};

UserSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    if (this.isModified('password')) {
        this._hashPassword(this.password);
    }

    next();
});

UserSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, { message: '{VALUE} already exists' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**auth.services**

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const JWTStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJWT = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const UserModel = require('../user/user.model');
const fs = require('fs');



// LocalStrategy
let localStrategy = new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'password' }, function(email, password, done) {

    UserModel.findOne({ email: email }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        } else if(!user) {
            // Invalid email
            return done(null, false);
        } else if(!user.authUser(password)) {
            // Invalid password
            return done(null, false);
        }

        return done(null, user);
    });
});

passport.use(localStrategy);


// JWTStrategy
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
const privateKEY = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/private.key', 'utf8');
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
const publicKEY = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/public.key', 'utf8');

let jwtStrategy = new JWTStrategy({
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    secretOrKey: publicKEY
}, function(payload, done) {

    UserModel.findById(payload._id, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        } else if(!user) {
            return done(null, false);
        }

        return done(null, user);
    });

});

passport.use(jwtStrategy);

module.exports = {
    authLocal: passport.authenticate('local', { session: false }),
    authJwt: passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
    privateKey: privateKEY
};
```

I can't see why it can't find the UserModel.findOne function, or maybe i am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was with the program flow. I used the auth.services in my user.model file to get ahold of my privateKey. This made me trying to use my model before it even were initialized.

Comment: Completely missed the fact you were pulling `auth.services`, glad you found the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your schema, you aren't *extending* the existing methods you are completely overwriting them i.e.

```
UserSchema.methods = { ... }
```

This line assigns a new object to `methods` which completely wipes out any existing functions (like `findOne`) that Mongoose provides. If you want to add static functions to the schema then you can extend `statics`

```
UserSchema.statics.myFunction = () => { ... }
```

Comment: Good point! But somehow the error still presists.. I even tried to commet my custom methods out, but its still the same error.

Comment: @Dondaj did you use `statics` and not `methods`?

Comment: `UserSchema.statics._hashPassword = async function(password) {
    this.password = await cryptor.hashAsync(password);
};` Yes, just like that. But somehow it still gives me the same error, i can't see why.. @James

Comment: It recognizes the findOne mongoose function when i export the Schema, and model in my auth.services file.`const UserModel = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);` like so. But that shouldn't be necessary?

Comment: @Dondaj nope, although it's narrowed the problem down to how the model is being exported. For some reason it doesn't seem to like the model being exported as the default, could you try defining the model in `user.model` as a var like in your previous comment and then exporting like `module.exports = { UserModel }`, then when importing `const UserModel = require('./user.model').UserModel`

Comment: This gave me a new error message, but still regarding the .findOne() function. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined`

Comment: @Dondaj doesn't sound like.you are exporting correctly